# What is the use of the "Repository" dropdown in Bitucket

Tags: compare, repository, bitbucket

The highlighted dropdown selections only show the current repo. Is there a setting to have it show the other repo's in the project?  Would be nice to be able to use Bitbucket to compare commits and branches across different repo's.

Web UI for Bitbucket Server compare page:
[image: Bitbucket compare]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `repository` dropdown is for comparing forks, based on their common commit history. If you don't use forking, then that particular dropdown is a bit useless, but you can still compare branches, tags, or commits within a repo.